# Request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, structure, union

I'm trying to do some saving/loading in my AppDelegate, for which I need my enemy and hero sprites. I'm using cocos2d. Here's the method that's getting the warning.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(UIApplication *)application {
 NSMutableArray *loadedMoles = [DataBase loadDocs];
 NSMutableArray *loadedBunnies = [DataBase loadDocs];
 UINavigationController *navigationController;
 viewController = (RootViewController *) [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
 viewController.mole = loadedMoles; //error
 viewController.bunny = loadedBunnies; //error
}
```

Even though this is the AppDelegate, I've imported both classes, and I'm still getting the errors.

Comment: what error do you have ?

Comment: The title of the question - Request for member in something not a structure or union

Comment: This is the tutorial I am following 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager

Cmd-F (find shortcut) and search "AppDelegate". It'll bring you to the section that I'm having a problem with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Relevant portion of comments

#### Jonathan

Given that the problem is not just `.` vs `->`, the other main option, then, is that your viewController does contain any moles or bunnies.

#### Joe

> I'm using the tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager.  (There is code there to download.)
>
> Doing:
>
> ```
> viewController->mole = loadedMoles;
> ```
>
> says
>
> ```
> 'struct RootViewController' has no member named 'mole'
> ```
>
> How do I add it to viewController?
>
> Although in the tutorial they use
>
> ```
> NSMutableArray *loadedBugs = [ScaryBugDatabase loadScaryBugDocs];
> RootViewController *rootController = (RootViewController *)
>                        [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
> rootController.bugs = loadedBugs;
> ```

#### Jonathan

In the downloaded code (`ScaryBugs3/Classes/rootViewController.h`), the demo has:

```
@class EditBugViewController;
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_bugs;
    EditBugViewController *_editBugViewController;
}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray *bugs;
@property (retain) EditBugViewController *editBugViewController;

@end
```

Does your equivalent have 'mole' and 'bunny' properly defined? If so, I'm at a loss to help you much further.

#### Joe

> I never downloaded the source code, so I didn't see any of that. Thanks, I was wondering if he might have bugs as an array instead of a bug sprite.

### Not very relevant portion of answer

In regular C or C++ with GCC, the error message normally occurs when either:

- You use `structptr->member` and you should use `structvar.member`, or
- You use `structvar.member` and you should use `structptr->member`.

Objective-C is close enough to C at this juncture that you probably need to review your use of `.` vs `->` notation, I believe.

Now that your code is legible, the lines giving the error are:

```
viewController.mole = loadedMoles; //error
viewController.bunny = loadedBunnies; //error
```

You probably need to use `viewController->mole` and `viewController->bunny` instead?  (I'm not sure of that, but to the extent Objective-C is a superset of C, that would be a necessary change.  However, it could be that Objective-C does away with the need to distinguish between `.` and `->`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not the case with ObjC

Comment: @JoeTheMonkey: The other main option, then, is that your viewController does contain any moles or bunnies.  I faintly remember seeing that Objective-C manages with `.` for both `.` and `->`, but hadn't looked it up to check.

Comment: Doing 'viewController->mole = loadedMoles;'
says 'struct RootViewController' has no member named 'mole'
How do I add it to viewController?

Comment: Although in the tutorial they use

NSMutableArray *loadedBugs = [ScaryBugDatabase loadScaryBugDocs];
RootViewController *rootController = (RootViewController *) [navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
rootController.bugs = loadedBugs;

Comment: In the downloaded code (ScaryBugs3/Classes/rootViewController.h), the demo has: `@class EditBugViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSMutableArray *_bugs;
    EditBugViewController *_editBugViewController;
}

@property (retain) NSMutableArray *bugs;
@property (retain) EditBugViewController *editBugViewController;

@end
`.   Does your equivalent have 'mole' and 'bunny' properly defined?  If so, I'm at a loss to help you much further.

Comment: I never downloaded the source code, so I didn't see any of that. Thanks, I was wondering if he might have bugs as an array instead of a bug sprite.

Answer (score 0):

At the link you gave is used RootViewController class and you are trying to use UINavigationController that simply does not have such properties as mole and bunny as @Jonathan said

Comment: In the tutorial he is using RootViewController and navigationController also

Comment: viewController is the name of my RootViewController

Answer (score 0):

I also had the error 'Request for member "options" in something not a structure or union' come up.

```
@interface Dialog :  NSManagedObject {}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* options;

@implementation Dialog
@dynamic options;
```

Where I simply forgot to import "Dialog.h" in the class that was trying to access this instance.